# Rest API not triggering JavaScript through android but working in browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, firebase, geofire

```
        <?php 




    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','eyukti_home_roc','4nYntQuCjPYR','eyukti_home_roc');

    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];


    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `vehicle_type` WHERE status = '1' AND is_delete !='1'"); 


    include("../firebase.php");       
    ?>

    <script>
    (function() {
      // Initialize the Firebase SDK
    firebase.initializeApp({
     databaseURL: "https://xxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com"
    });

    var  user_new_lat = null;
    var  user_new_lng = null;

    var ref_driver_location = firebase.database().ref('Driver/DriverLocation');

    var  ref_user = firebase.database().ref('User').child('<?php echo $user_id; ?>');
    var ref_nearest_driver = ref_user.child('NearestDriver');
    var ref_availableDriver = ref_user.child('availableDriver');
    var ref_driver = firebase.database().ref('Driver');
    var geoFire = new geofire.GeoFire(ref_driver_location);


    var user_new_location = ref_user.child('UserLocation/UserLocationNew');
    var user_old_location = ref_user.child('UserLocation/UserLocationOld');


    var user_location = ref_user.child('UserLocation');

         var user_new = ref_user.child('UserLocation/GeoLocation');

    var geoQuery = null;


    user_old_location.on("value", function(newuser_snapshot) {


    user_location.once("value", function(nearest_driver_snapshot) {

           user_new_lat = nearest_driver_snapshot.child("GeoLocation/location/l/0").val();
           user_new_lng = nearest_driver_snapshot.child("GeoLocation/location/l/1").val();  
         var user_old_lat = nearest_driver_snapshot.child("UserLocationOld/lat").val();
         var user_old_lng = nearest_driver_snapshot.child("UserLocationOld/lng").val();



                var geoFireUserLocation = new geofire.GeoFire(user_new);     
                var geoQueryUserLocation = geoFireUserLocation.query({
                    //alert('yes');
                  center: [parseFloat(user_old_lat),parseFloat(user_old_lng)],
                  radius: 0.6
                });


                     var onReadyRegistration = geoQueryUserLocation.on("ready", function() {
                  console.log("GeoQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data");
                });


                var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQueryUserLocation.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {


                                 geoQuery = geoFire.query({
                                  center: [parseFloat(user_old_lat),parseFloat(user_old_lng)],
                                  radius: 3.0
                                });










    }, function (error) {
       console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });



    }, function (error) {
       console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });


    })();


    </script>

    <!--<script src="../firebase_js/insertuser.js" defer></script>-->
```

Issue is this firebase Geofire working when i hit this api from browser but not hitting when i call this api in android
I tried to call API in postman to but it is giving response from php but not triggering geofire function and also giving javascript code in response . i am not able to find solution because i am not able to find the problem

Comment: in android are you using webview in app or using chrome?

Comment: i am calling this api through Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webview in android, you need to enable javascript for webview as follows

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
mWebView.loadUrl("htpps://yoururl");
```

Comment: this is a rest api not a URL

Comment: ok, may be you have set the php file path in retrofit, that's y it's giving the entire file in response, you need to set the API endpoint in retrofir

Comment: yes but issue is all these GeoFire , Firebase function not trigger when i hit this api from android

Comment: re-verify  if you are using same path in postman and in retrofit

Comment: issue i am facing in postman is same as in android, php code is giving response in postman but still not triggering script functions


edit-Verifed stucked in problem from 3 days

Comment: on Godady  server

Comment: looks like you have missed something, after uploading the file you might have to do some initialisation or something

Comment: but it is working when i hit api directly in browser

Comment: ok got it, then you can do one thing is, use webview in android, check the link for sample https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm, and i'm edditing the above answer load the url in android webview, don't use retrofit

Comment: i am hitting this API just to trigger these function i have nothing to show on webview  infact i have some json response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207517/discussion-between-shekhar-saini-and-ked).

Comment: ok, what you have done is i think accessing Firebase API's  from javascript in browser, you should write accessing Firebase using PHP application, hope this will help https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=1

Comment: i have dojne everything accordingly

Comment: i tried using webView also but issue is still same , thing is javascript is working but geofire function are working only  through browser